# Host mail server and website on different machines under one domain

Tags: linux, email, web

Is there a way to host mail server for certain domain on different machine.

For example:
If I own website.com and it is hosted on PC1 what are the requirements to make mail.website.com and host it on PC2.

I am planning to use Linux Ubuntu-postfix-squirrel mail...

Comment: There are many different ways this could be done. In general, you simply configure mail on PC2 and web on PC1 to serve traffic (mail or web) for your domain as if they were independent. Then you just configure DNS to route email to the mail server via MX records (and web traffic to the web server via normal A records).

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly normal.

In your DNS config you'll specify one or more `MX` record types - these are the hosts responsible for handling mail for your domain.   Note that they do not need to be hosts in your domain - ie, you can pay MS or Google for mail service, and you'd set your `MX` records to point to the MS or Google server.

Then for the website portion, normal `A` or `CNAME` records are used to point to a host.